# Xamarin Forms bindable properties vs normal properties

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I don't understand what bindable properties offer more than normal ones. Perhaps the PropertyChanged event? But I guess you could write in your normal property setter whatever you'd write in the PropertyChanged event. One simple example with these two might make it click in my head. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties)

> The purpose of bindable properties is to provide a property system
> that supports data binding, styles, templates, and values set through
> parent-child relationships. In addition, bindable properties can
> provide default values, validation of property values, and callbacks
> that monitor property changes.